# Userforms with a listbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post on this forum.  I have a quick question regarding VBA, Userforms with a listbox.  My goal is to select two options and return a list of names in a listbox.  I have attached the example userform and the example table that I would be choosing from.  Any help would be appreciated.

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vkiy.jpg)

[Current VBA for Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdpLM.jpg)

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Sheets("Trainers1").Range("I2") = ListBox1


End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Click()

Sheets("Trainers1").Range("I2") = ListBox2


End Sub

Private Sub ListBox3_Click()

Sheets("Trainers1").Range("I3") = ListBox3

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox4_Change()

.ListBox4 = Sheets("Trainers1").Range("K2:K10")

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cnt
Dim cntr As Integer

cntr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Shift Pattern Key").Range("A:A"))
cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Training Ratio").Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To cntr


ListBox2.AddItem Sheets("Shift Pattern Key").Cells(i, 1)

Next i

For i2 = 2 To cnt

ListBox3.AddItem Sheets("Training Ratio").Cells(i2, 1)

Next i2

End Sub
```

Comment: First, what have you tried? SO will not write the whole code for you, but we would all be more than happy to help you through issues. Second, you need to provide more information. What values will be selected? And how do you use those to make the selection of the name? This is entirely possible, but you need to help us help you.

Comment: I adjusted my current post and included two different pictures that may help.  Sorry for the confusion since its my first post.  I cant get it to list the employee names that fit the criteria in the listbox.

Comment: Can you please explain the criteria? I can guess at what specifically that criteria is, but would rather have your explanation as you already know it.

Comment: Well the two criteria are the shiftcode and the class.  So for instance if you select PT310 and TDR, the box in the middle should show the trainers that meet these two critieria.

Comment: So class corresponds with `Trained` on the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the rows of your table and compare the values in each row to the values selected. If both values in a row match the values selected by the user you can then use the .AddItem method to add the name of the employee to the list.